# How to use a Maven artifact as input of another artifact (or module)?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have an original java webapp (that thus produces a WAR file) which is Maven-managed, let's call it `webapp`.

I like to keep its Maven configuration as it is, but at times I need to, say, post-produce that generated WAR by manipulating its contents (or anyway apply generic operations on it).

So I made a multimodule project:

```
- multimodule
    +-- webapp
    +-- operator
```

The `operator` could do several things. For instance, it calls a (Java) command line program that does some checks on a WAR: how do I take the 'webapp' module output (i.e. the WAR file) and set it as input of the `operator` module?

I have no clue on how to do this nor on what to search on the net, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `webapp` a dependency of the `operator` project.

Sample POM of `operator`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>my-groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>operator</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my-groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

By creating an explicit dependency, Maven will build the webapp before the `operator` project in the reactor and you will be able to post-process that war.

Let's take an example by considering that you want to invoke a program taking this war as argument.

First, this new dependency has to be copied to a specific location. This is done with the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). This plugin has a goal [`copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) which is used to copy all direct dependencies of a project to a location in the filesystem. Sample configuration would be:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<plugin>
```

Now that the dependency is available in the filesystem, you can run a program using the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html). Sample configuration, launching `operator -param1 webapp.war`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <configuration>
            <executable>operator</executable>
            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-param1</argument>
                <argument>webapp.war</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But, my doubts arise right here: how do I go on? For instance, let's say that `operator` is a program that should be invoked like this: `operator -param1 webapp.war`, what should I do in `operator` POM?

Comment: Nice! One more thing: since `webapp.war` is made from a dependency, can I retrieve it through a property or some other dynamic way, so that I don't have to edit the `<argument>` text every time I change, e.g., the dependency version?

Comment: @watery you can always use the property `${project.version}` to get the version dynamically

Comment: I was looking more toward something like `${dependency1}` - it should resolve to `webapp-<defined-version>.war` or similar. That would be the best, otherwise I already found the `<destFileName />` configuration to rename a single dependency

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

You should be able to define two profiles and configure second profile to do your additional operations. If you follow this approach, you won't need two modules.

Comment: Actually, my setting is a bit different: my main aim is to pass two similar WARs to an external program (I've simplified here), so a module for each of them is a must; plus, I'd like to keep each WAR build configuration separated from additional and variable operations, so I think profiles don't fit here.